# Validating Against Property of 2nd Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As part of my objective of learning a new skill at work I am attempting to develop an employee management system in ASP.NET MVC (MVC 4).

I am trying to follow the convention of performing all validation at the model level (not only because this is what I have read is recommended but also as there is talk of a desktop app that may use parts of the model so I want to ensure any constraints are enforced in that app too!).

My issue is, I have some data on the Person class (RemainingHoliday). When create a HolidayRequest I want to ensure that the request is not for a greater number of days than the person has remaining.

How would I go about doing this?  I know that I can create my own validation rules by extending the ValidationAttribute, but how would I get from the HolidayRequest class to the Person class within here?

A snippet of the models:

```
public class Person
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; } // this is populated with Users AD Guid
    public string HolidayEntitlement { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HolidayRequest> Holidays { get; set; }

    public int TotalEntitlement(int year = -1)
    {
        return this.HolidayEntitlement + this.HolidayAdjustments.Where(a => a.LeaveYear.Year == year).Sum(a => a.Adjustment);
    }

    public int RemainingHoliday(int year = -1)
    {
        return this.TotalEntitlement(year) - this.Holidays.Where(h => h.Start.Year == year).Where(h => h.Status != HolidayStatus.Rejected).Sum(h => h.Duration);
    }
}

public class HolidayRequest
{
    public string HolidayId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Finish { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; } // This cannot be greater than Person.RemainingHoliday
}
```

I would really appreciate any pointers or samples for this, or perhaps I am trying to be too ideal and this cannot be done in the model?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing a reference to the person requesting the  holiday in the HolidayRequest object.  I would have expected to see a Person or PersonId in the HolidayRequest object.  Once there, you could compute the difference between Duration and RemainingHoliday.

Comment: I'm using the entity framework so the reference is taken care of by the virtual ICollection on the Person class, at least I do appear to have a PersonId field on my requests DB table